# Loop with addEventListener is not dynamic for function()

Tags: javascript, debugging, for-loop, dynamic, addeventlistener

I want to make an extremely easy for loop to call a function with a different parameter for each button. However, when I run the call and click the button, the eventListener function saveList(listIdx) only returns the function saveList("5"). PLease take a look at my problem and trouble shooting.

```
    for (var listIdx = 0; listIdx < count; listIdx++ ) {
            console.log("setting the variable" + "myButton" + listIdx );

            document.getElementById("myButton" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", function() { saveList(listIdx); 
            });
    }
```

Attempt 1: Add a parameter to the function() call

```
    for (var listIdx = 0; listIdx < count; listIdx++ ) {
            console.log("setting the variable" + "myButton" + listIdx );

            document.getElementById("myButton" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", function(listIdx) { saveList(listIdx); 
            });
    }
```

Attempt 2: wrapper on the element

```
    for (var listIdx = 0; listIdx < count; listIdx++ ) {
            console.log("setting the variable" + "myButton" + listIdx );

            document.getElementById("myButton" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", function(_listIdx) { saveList(_listIdx); 
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that function is being called at a later point in time – after for loop is finished. The variable contained in the body has already been updated in the last iteration of for loop. That's what you are seeing.

The fix is to somehow push the variable to the function inside.

```
function makeListSaver(index) {
    /* return a brand new function that has captured the index when this function 
       was invoked
    */
    return function() { 
        saveList(index);
    }
}
```

and then do,

```
document.getElementById("myButton" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", makeListSaver(listIdx))
```

---

Or simply,

```
document.getElementById("myButton" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", (function(index){
   return function() { saveList(index); }
})(listIdx));
```

You'll have to read up a little bit on closures and how they work.

Comment: do you if the parenthesis are right? I get a function which looks like

Comment: `addEventListener("click", (function(index){
                                               return function() { saveList(index); }
                          })(listIdx));`

Comment: Parenthesis look fine to me. What error are you facing ?

Comment: The first one works, I can understand more behind the concept, than the second attempt `function() { makeListSave(listIdx)` is different then `makeListSaver(listIdx)` ? Is that what its about?

Comment: Both the versions are identical. The first version was an attempt to explain the idea behind the fix. The second version is just a compact version of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the loop.

Here a quick example of how to set `addEventListener` in a `for` loop.

http://jsbin.com/kavowucimi/1/

How does it works:

- When page load
- Find all elements with class obj.
- For each element add an event listener click.
- When user click, alerts id for selected element.

---

```
<script>
    window.app = {
        start: function(){
            var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.obj');

            for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++ ) {
                var t = elms[i];
                var elm = document.getElementById(t.id);
                elm.addEventListener('click', function(item){
                    alert(item.currentTarget.id);
                });
            }
        }
    };

    </script>

<body onload="window.app.start();">
<div id=1 class="obj">1</div>
<div id=2 class="obj">2</div>
<div id=3 class="obj">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way...

```
for (var listIdx = 0; listIdx < count; listIdx++ ) {
           applyEvent(listIdx);
    }

function applyEvent(listIdx)
{   
        document.getElementById("1" + listIdx).addEventListener("click", function({                
              saveList(listIdx); 
        });
}
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/d9o96y2L/)**

Comment: Nice fiddle, do you think fiddles are useful besides showing code. Can you run websites from them? I want to start a dynamic and interactive blog website. Would I want to use fiddle for that?

Comment: @collegeWaldo Hi, I think the main idea of fiddle is a faster way to share snippets of code and editing. I think does not fit with your porpoise.

Comment: @collegeWaldo, Why dont you give me your FTP details then, I will directly code it their. Dude, Fiddle is just a way to let you show what my works. What is the problem in that? I guess i also pasted it here what i coded their.